# Using Devise with CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, authorization, cancan

This might be a bit of a noob question, but I'm asking anyway.

So I'm building an app where people make posts. So it's a social network.

But I don't want people to be able to edit and delete other's posts.

I don't think a role-based system would work here, because people only administrate their own posts **only**.

I was thinking some sort of AR association, but I don't know if that would work.

What I want is something like this for my `app/models/ability.rb`:

```
class Ability
  def initialize(user)
    if current_user.username == @post.username
      can :edit, Post
      can :destroy, Post
    end
  end 
end
```

How would I go about doing this (assuming the models are `User` and `Post`)?

So basically should I do a [User has Posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHyeq.png), or User has and belongs to [Posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD1Dq.png)?

Comment: What problems are you actually having? Have you tried that? Also, don't you associate a user to the post? Why not `current_user == @post.user`. Or `@post.owner`

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu The question is how I would go about doing that, e.g. `has_many`, `has_one`, `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
class Ability
  def initialize(user)
    can [:edit, :destroy], Post do |post|
      post.try(:user) == user
    end
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that class `Ability` won't have access to the `@post` instance variable. So I think in `Ability.rb` you would have to say that users `can :manage, Post` so they can create, edit and destroy Post objects. Then it's up to your controller and model layers to ensure that they can only edit and destroy their own Posts.

With CanCan you can call `load_and_authorize_resource` at the top of a controller to protect the entire thing, but in your case your `PostsController` will probably need to protect at the action level. Calling `authorize! :manage, @post` in the `create`, `destroy`, `edit` and `update` actions, for example, along with checking to make sure that the `current_user.username == @post.username`, can ensure that people can modify only their own posts.

Finally, instead of actually deleting posts, you may want users to instead "soft-delete" by simply marking a Post as deleted. In this case, you would explicitly authorize the creation and editing of Posts, but you would not authorize them to actually `destroy` Posts. In your `index` and `show` actions, you would ensure that Posts marked as deleted were not shown.

As to role-based systems, down the road you may want a group of moderators or to add on another administrator. That's when you'll want a role-based system. I almost always make mine role-based to start with, even if it's just to have `admin` and `user` roles.